# Mysql converting subquery into dependent subquery

Tags: mysql

Hi I am not understanding , why the subquery of given query is converting into dependent subquery.

Although the subquery is not dependent(not using primary query table) on main query.

I know that this query can be optimized using joins,but here i just want to know the reason of this

```
MYSQL Version 5.5

EXPLAIN SELECT id  FROM  `cab_request_histories` 
WHERE cab_request_histories.id = any(SELECT id
                                     FROM cab_requests
                                     WHERE cab_requests.request_type =  'pickup')

id   select_type      table type           possible_keys     key               key_len  ref rows Extra
1    PRIMARY    cab_request_histories   index             NULL             PRIMARY  4   NULL    20                       

2    DEPENDENT       SUBQUERY          cab_requests unique_subquery    PRIMARY  PRIMARY 4 func  1
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the ANY keyword will require MySQL to pass the values from outside the subquery to inside it to evaluate whether the result is true.

Comment: does the subquery is executing for every row  of primary query?,

Comment: I think possibly so. It is having to check if each id is equal to the id in the histories table (probably not required when using = ANY, but it would cope with > ANY and it is possibly not optimised for = ANY when an IN clause or JOIN would be the more natural choices)

Answer (score 1):

Mysql optimizer uses EXIST strategy for this query, effectively changing it to something like:

```
SELECT id  FROM  cab_request_histories
WHERE EXISTS 
  ( SELECT 'this one is dependent' FROM cab_requests
    WHERE cab_requests.request_type =  'pickup' 
    AND cab_requests.id = cab_request_histories.id )
```

You can see what optimizer does with your query using `EXPLAIN EXTENDED your_query` followed by `SHOW WARNINGS`.

This type of optimization is described in http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/subquery-optimization-with-exists.html.